# Facebook not giving permission to access users uploaded photos

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Invalid Scopes: user_photos. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

```
function login( callback ) {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                //console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                if (callback) {
                    callback(response);
                }
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        },{scope: 'user_photos'} );
    }
```

Comment: did you check out the changelog?

Comment: Yes i check  @luschn

Comment: _“This permission is restricted to a limited set of partners and usage requires prior approval by Facebook.”_ - so you are one of those partners, or …?

Comment: No Then how to do that ? @CBroe

Comment: then there is no way. you should always check out the breaking changes and the changelog if something does not work (anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_photos

> This permission is restricted to a limited set of partners and usage requires prior approval by Facebook.